# Need help on using flutter sign_in_with_apple package

Tags: flutter, firebase, hosting, apple-sign-in, apple-login

I am trying to implement apple login through my flutter firebase app.
I've done all the process for apple sign in such as appple app id registration, service id registration, ios set up, and firebase hosting.

So I used sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0 for my app and I am trying to use example code from the package description. However, if I run the code there are 2 errors to solve

Error: Error when reading 'lib/presenter/firebase/auth/html_shim.dart': No such file or directory

Error: Undefined name 'window'.

[image]

i will leave the package link below
https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple/example